# How to augment a list of contacts

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

My app shows the contact list and I want to show some additional dynamic information for some of the contacts.  Options I've thought of so far include the following.

1. Create a matrix cursor containing all the contacts plus my additional information.  I don't like this idea as there may be a very large number of contacts.  But it should be fast when it comes to rendering the views.
2. When I get the cursor for the contacts also build a hash table with my additional information.  Then pass both to the CursorAdapter and get it to look up in the hash table as it binds views.  I imagine this should be fast enough as hash tables are fast.

I'm leaning towards 2.  Any better ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went for the hash-table route.  I've also tried building an "augmented" cursor that adds an extra column by internalising the hash-table.